# How to change cassandra.yaml inside kubernetes pods?

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to update a few properties inside `cassandra.yaml`.
I have a cluster of 5 nodes running inside Kubernetes as pods.
I have found that in `values.yaml` of `Helm` if we change `configOverrides:` properties and do helm upgrade then it should work.

My steps

1. Added all contents of `cassandra.yaml` (tried both YAML and JSON format).
2. Run *helm upgrade command* (it runs without error after multiple attempts of changing point 1 contents)
3. Restart pods, I just deleted the pod expecting Kubernetes will spin up one. However, it does not happen.

If I revert the change then the pod which I deleted will spin up as expected.
I am not sure how to do this. If anyone can point me what I am doing wrong that will be helpful.

UPDATE

Since I have been asked to keep my Question in SO guidelines. Actually there is not much to add. Anyway, I will try to elaborate a bit,

I am trying to change properties inside `cassandra.yaml` like *ENABLE_USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION* which is by default `false`. In my local machine, I can change this file, restart docker container and all set.

However, on production env, where the Cassandra cluster is hosted inside Kubernetes, I am not seeing any straightway to achieve the same thing.

Options are

1. As described above and looks more ideal solution.
2. Build a docker image on top of the official Cassandra image with all the needed properties enabled.

UPDATE #2

```
kubeclt logs

INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2020-07-15 20:48:25,004 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:78 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2020-07-15 21:45:54,078 Gossiper.java:1105 - InetAddress /###.##.##.## is now DOWN
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-cassandra-0.cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/###.##.##.##] 2020-07-15 21:45:55,613 OutboundTcpConnection.java:561 - Handshaking version with cassandra-0.cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/###.##.##.##
```

Comment: Please refer to stackoverflow guidlines on how to [Create Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-examplea)

Comment: @HelloWorld The link you shared is broken.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What does kubectl logs return for the pods?

Comment: @vitalyros added last few lines of logs. I do not see any warnings/error.

Comment: I was hoping you could provide example of `configOverrides:` and maybe the version of the helm chart you are using, but since you didn't I will try to guess.
My best guess is that it doesn't work because configOverrides [mounts volume and hides all files in /etc/cassandra](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/incubator/cassandra/templates/statefulset.yaml#L169-L173) so you would probably need to explicitly deploy all the files from /etc/cassandra dir. You could also open an [issue on github charts repo](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues) and ask people who wrote it to help you.

Comment: I also tried to replicate your issue but for some reason it doesn't work at all on my cluster and because of my lack of knowledge of cassandra I dont know how to debug this.